# Flask-Restful POST fails due CSRF protection of Flask-WTF

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-restful

I am using normal flask web + flask-restful. So I need CSRF protection for web but not for REST.

The moment I enable `CsrfProtect(app)` of `flask-wtf`, all my post unit tests for `flask-restful` return a 400.

Is there a way to disable CSRF protection for REST services since they are coming from mobile handsets without session handling anyway, hence CSRF wouldn't make much sense.

This is how I test it:

```
rv = self.client.post('api/v1.0/verify-email', environ_base={'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1'}, headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'}, data=json.dumps(data))
self.check_content_type(rv.headers)
eq_(rv.status_code, 412)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the [`@csrf.exempt` decorator](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#flask_wtf.csrf.CsrfProtect.exempt), which you need to add  directly on the API object, with the [`decorators` argument](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#id1); this would apply the decorator to *all* API routes:

```
csrf_protect = CsrfProtect(app)
api = restful.Api(app, decorators=[csrf_protect.exempt])
```

You cannot use [resource method decorators](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending.html#resource-method-decorators) as they are not the final view functions that the `exempt` decorator requires to work.

It appears you cannot protect individual resources and exempt others; this is a limitation in the method used by Flask-Wtf's method of recording what views are exempted.

Comment: Thats an interesting solution. When try to run it it says `method_decorators = [csrf.exempt]` -> `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'exempt'`. I am importing: `from flask_wtf import csrf`

Comment: Not the module, the extension object. I've updated the answer to make this a little more obvious as well as add another method to apply the decorator to all API routes.

Comment: The second solution is brilliant. It works, thank you so much Martijn.

Comment: Indeed, adjusted the answer; method decorators would not work.

Answer (score 8):

More simple solution ([related commit](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/commit/e8644562b1e2f571027765a6f9c33b6fb5ce802c)):

```
csrf.exempt(api_blueprint)
```

And here is a complete demo:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_wtf import CSRFProtect

app = Flask(__name__)
csrf = CSRFprotect(app)

api_blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__)
csrf.exempt(api_blueprint)

app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint)
```

Comment: This was perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and I kept getting a generic 401 Unauthorized error, while my postman calls were working absolutely fine. It took me a while to figure out that this was because I had enabled CSRF for my web-based forms. But my backend calls were served by Restful endpoints and CSRF Protection doesn't work with restful calls.

Here's how I fixed it:

In my settings file,

I set JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT to False and that fixed my restful post calls.

Note:

Since you are setting this field in the global settings file, this action will disable CSRF Protection for all the API calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can also disbale CSRF protection by setting the `WTF_CSRF_ENABLED` to False. This comes handy in your unit tests. For example, when you create a test app that you use in your unit tests and disable `WTF_CSRF_ENABLED` the tests shouldn't throw a CSRF token missing error:

```
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_mapping({'WTF_CSRF_ENABLED':False})
app.test_client().get("/api/v1/")
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to CSRF protect a single API endpoint on a flask-restful blueprint could be done by checking the path with an @app.before_request decorator and activate protection on demand.

```
@app.before_request
def csrf_protect():
    if request.path.startswith("/api/v1/resource"):
        csrf.protect()
```

A precondition is that you have set the setting

```
WTF_CSRF_CHECK_DEFAULT = False
```

Answer (score -2):

You could set WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False in your test_config.
If you only want to disable it for your tests that is.