# How to disable csrf for a view with flask-wft for a restapi?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-restful

I get problem for disable csrf using flask-wtf for a restapi. The problem is similar like here: [Flask-Restful POST fails due CSRF protection of Flask-WTF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509728/flask-restful-post-fails-due-csrf-protection-of-flask-wtf#21509994), but I use flask original instead of flask-restful.

I use the [`@csrf.exempt`decorator](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_wtf.csrf.CSRFProtect.exempt), and I did exactly like the documentation, but still can not disable the csrf. Here is my code, do you know what is the problem?

**myApp.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

app = Flask(__name__)    
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "secret"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

csrf = CSRFProtect(app) # initialize the csrf protect

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String())

class myForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField("user name")

@app.route("/check", methods=['POST'])    
@csrf.exempt # why this code doesn't work???!!! :(
def check():
    form = myForm(request.form)

    if form.validate():
        user = User(username=form.username.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(message="user saved!"), 200
    else:
        return jsonify(message=form.errors), 404

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My Postman always return:

```
{
    "message": {
        "csrf_token": [
            "The CSRF token is missing."
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`FlaskForm.validate()` seems to be the one returning that error, i.e. try

```python
form = myForm(request.form, csrf_enabled=False)
```

or

```python
class myForm(FlaskForm):
    class Meta:
        csrf = False

     username = StringField("user name")
```

since `csrf_enabled` seems to be deprecated.

From the documentation

> Any view using FlaskForm to process the request is already getting CSRF protection.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer! Do you mean the `csrf_enabled` in `myForm()` is deprecated? It currently works wunderful. Another question is if I use `class Meta: crsf = False`, then I will disable all the csrf protection, actually, I only want disable a part of them for the restapi...  Is there any way to use the use the `@csrf.exempt`?

Comment: There was a deprecation warning about `csrf_enabled` when I executed the flask application. Use of `class Meta..` in `myForm` should be limited to instances of class `myForm`. I think decorators provided by an instance of `CSRFProtect` are meant for views that do not call `FlaskForm.validate()`, so probably no.

Answer (score 12):

You can pass meta={'csrf': False} as parameter in your constructor

```
form = myForm(request.form, meta={'csrf': False})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the route[s] you would like to exclude to csrf as a string:

```
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
csrf.exempt('app.blueprints.views.my_view_fn')
```